# Argurment 1 cannot convert from 'method group' to Bitmap. (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Studio (Android). I'm trying to save a signature gesture from a gestureView as a bitmap. Please see my code below, and note this works fine on Android Studio (Java), Thanks in advance.

```
gestureView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
bm = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(gestureView.GetDrawingCache);

File f = new File(docFolder + "/signature.png");
f.CreateNewFile();
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, bs);
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetDrawingCache()` is a method and needs parentheses

```
bm = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(gestureView.GetDrawingCache());
```

Comment: I made that change but still can't save the image. When trying to compress the bitmap - bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, bs); I'm getting this : Error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Java.IO.ByteArrayOutputStream' to 'System.IO.Stream' (CS1503)

Comment: the third argument needs to be a .NET System.IO.Stream, not a Java stream